# Couldn't load opencv_java3

Tags: android, opencv, android-studio

I'm trying to use VideoCapture from opencv but I have this error :

```
11-02 13:50:02.209 16755-16755/? W/System.err: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load opencv_java3 from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/org.opencv.samples.puzzle15-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/org.opencv.samples.puzzle15-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib, /system/lib/arm]]]: findLibrary returned null
11-02 13:50:02.209 16755-16755/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:358)
11-02 13:50:02.209 16755-16755/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
11-02 13:50:02.209 16755-16755/? W/System.err:     at org.opencv.android.StaticHelper.loadLibrary(StaticHelper.java:64)
11-02 13:50:02.209 16755-16755/? W/System.err:     at org.opencv.android.StaticHelper.initOpenCVLibs(StaticHelper.java:95)
11-02 13:50:02.209 16755-16755/? W/System.err:     at org.opencv.android.StaticHelper.initOpenCV(StaticHelper.java:39)
11-02 13:50:02.209 16755-16755/? W/System.err:     at org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader.initDebug(OpenCVLoader.java:72)
11-02 13:50:02.209 16755-16755/? W/System.err:     at org.opencv.samples.puzzle15.Puzzle15Activity.onCreate(Puzzle15Activity.java:62)
11-02 13:50:02.209 16755-16755/? W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
11-02 13:50:02.209 16755-16755/? W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
11-02 13:50:02.209 16755-16755/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2218)
11-02 13:50:02.209 16755-16755/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2304)
11-02 13:50:02.209 16755-16755/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:142)
11-02 13:50:02.209 16755-16755/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1255)
11-02 13:50:02.209 16755-16755/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-02 13:50:02.209 16755-16755/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
11-02 13:50:02.209 16755-16755/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5097)
11-02 13:50:02.209 16755-16755/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-02 13:50:02.209 16755-16755/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-02 13:50:02.209 16755-16755/? W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
11-02 13:50:02.209 16755-16755/? W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:610)
11-02 13:50:02.209 16755-16755/? W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

For the moment I just want to create the VideoCapture but it doesn't work. This is my code
    private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {

```
    @Override
    public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
        switch (status) {
            case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
            {
                Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");

                /* Now enable camera view to start receiving frames */
                mOpenCvCameraView.setOnTouchListener(Puzzle15Activity.this);
                mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();
            } break;
            default:
            {
                super.onManagerConnected(status);
            } break;
        }
    }
};

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Internal OpenCV library not found. Using OpenCV Manager for initialization");
        OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_3_0_0, this, mLoaderCallback);
    }
    VideoCapture cv=new VideoCapture(); 
}
```

I am using android studio and opencv 3.0.0.

Comment: I've seen examples put the calls to initDebug() and initAsync() in onResume() instead of onCreate()--may not be your problem though.  I believe initDebug() looks for the native libs in your apk, and initAsync() trys to use OpenCV Manager installed on device.  Can you tell which one of those its using?

Comment: I try to put it in onResume() but it's not changing anything and I think it's using initAsync()

Comment: Do you see the output of this log stmt in your log?    Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");  Is OpenCV Manager installed on your device?  What device are your running it on?